# How to use environment variables to set some parameters instead of parameters.yml?

Tags: symfony, parameters, environment-variables, symfony-3.4

I am trying to set my database name and password as environment variables in symfony 3.4 app

I already did change the values inside the config file to:

```
    dbname: '%env(DB_NAME)%'
    user: '%env(DB_USER)%'
    password: '%env(DB_PASSWORD)%'
```

this is the error i am getting it seems its not checking env() at all

> You have requested a non-existent parameter "env(DB_NAME)".

Am I missing something here? I tried also the dotenv component but I could not install it with symfony 3.4.

Comment: what is the error you are getting when you are trying to install Dotenv Component?

Comment: - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.28
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.4.27

 Installation request for symfony/symfony ^3.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.2, v3.4.20, v3.4.21, v3.4.22, v3.4.23, v3.4.24, v3.4.25, v3.4.26, v3.4.27, v3.4.28, v3.4.3, v3.4.4, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9].
    - Installation request for symfony/dotenv ^4.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/dotenv[v4.3.0, v4.3.1].

Comment: i guess its somthing related to the versions but in the symfony documentaions the EV should work without extra component to use

Comment: "symfony/dotenv ^4.3" Sort of looks like you are trying to install the 4.3 version instead of 3.4.

Comment: i just did "composer require symfony/dotenv" without specifying any version

Comment: Did je set the parameter `env(DB_NAME)`? See https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/configuration/external_parameters.html for more information.

Comment: not defining the variable will generate another error but it seems that something wrong in my app because when i tried this in fresh installed version of Symfony its working without any problem

Answer (score 1):

I found what causing the error after installing "UnifikDatabaseConfigBundle" it adds to the AppKernel a function:

```
protected function getContainerBuilder()
{
    return new ContainerBuilder(new ParameterBag($this->getKernelParameters()));
}
```

and this function causing this error thanks every one for your help